# Set app as default Assist Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So currently at my wits end for this issue.

I am trying to set my app as the default app launched when long pressing the Home button.

I am doing this by:

1. Setting Intent Filters in the manifest (I also experimented with adding MAIN and LAUNCHER action/category  tags)

> ```
>  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
>  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
>  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
> ```

2. Requesting the default app on an intent to allow users to change (there's also one for the Search Long Press action)

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ASSIST);
> intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
> intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> ```

This approach works perfectly fine for devices running pre 6.0 software.
On post 6 devices the request is asked but the default assistant app is unchanged.

My app can be set as the default home app on post 6 devices perfectly fine when using these exact steps.

I'm unsure as to whether there's some kind of specific permission I'm missing or something. Nothing seems to work at all. The google app will always be used on long press. If I disable the google app then my app will run on long press.

**Extra information:** This is a kiosk app for business so I prefer to not have to disable the Google app for every single device this will go on. I don't mind if solutions are hacky as this is not going on the app store.

Comment: "On post 6 devices the request is asked but the default assistant app is unchanged" -- that gets changed in the Settings app, last I checked.

Comment: Is there any official documentation stating this?

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

To implement your Assistant like app, the assistant app must provide an implementation of `VoiceInteractionSessionService` and `VoiceInteractionSession`.
It also requires the `BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION` permission.

See also:

- [Implementing Your Own Assistant](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant#implementing_your_own_assistant)
- [VoiceInteraction sample app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/tests/VoiceInteraction/)

Comment: This seems to be for voice assistance. My question was for launching the correct app when long pressing the home button.

Comment: Only voice interaction app can be launch by pressing long home.

Comment: I've done a lot of testing with this but I think one of the comments on my original question may be correct. Other apps (such as microsofts Cortana) take you to the settings screen to manually change it. This answer allows the app to be an option for assistant (which wasn't an issue before) but unfortunately doesn't persist unless manually changed in the settings screen.